# How to post to private FB Group with API while in development?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook user, who created a Faecbook app, and also is the administrator of a private group.  I am building a website to post to the group.

So, I want to Facebook Connect from my site, connecting my user to the Facebook app, and getting special permissions to then post to the Group.

Here's how I understand Facebook's permissions for posting to a Group (and in this case, a secret group):

- I need special permissions, such as publish_actions, for my app's scope.
- To get those permissions, I have to file a special request.  This special request requires links to my website/app, where Facebook can see how I am using the permissions.  It's quite a detailed app.
- I can't finish the app to show them, though, because I don't have permissions to post to a Group... so the app can't be finished, so I have nothing to show them.

This seems contradictory.  What am I missing?  Is there a developer-only mode, where just my user (who administers the app and the group) can auto-approve these special permissions, for testing purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Permissions work without Review for everyone with a role in the App (Admin, Developer, Tester). Make sure you got a Test User in your App, that´s what Facebook will use.

Btw, you would need `user_groups` too, and you will not get that one approved at all: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference-user_groups

Comment: Thanks.  If I can never get user_groups, how does Buffer app have approval to do Group Wall posts?

Comment: by using an old v1.0 app. it will stop working for them after april 2015.